# Why doesn't Find Usages in IDEA/AS show all results?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

So I have a case where `Find Usages` doesn't return hits from a particular class of mine. I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2. The class is used in a method paramter, is a part of the main source code base and module, and does pop up when I do a free text `Find in Path`

Have I somehow removed the file `VgXitiLogger.java` from indexing? Where in that case do I configure that?

[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "Find Usages" screenshot shows the usages of the constructor of the SearchPerformedEvent class, because you triggered Find Usages when the caret was on the constructor of the class. The occurrences on the second screenshot are usages of the class, not of the constructor.